# How to use an accounting/currency format for an entire column in shiny renderTable?

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable, shiny, format

I am currently experiencing difficulties with trying to format a column in a datatable from renderTable. The table is being rendered from a dataframe that I have defined. That dataframe is then filtered using user input and a subset to form the dataframe that is shown when implementing the output. Is there an easy way to apply an accounting/currency format to one column of the Data table output? I have added code below for reference:

UI:

```
tableOutput("datetest")
```

SERVER:

```
df6 <- data.frame(Account_Num,Account_Num_Spec,Account_Name,Billing_Num,Date,Tran_Type,Transaction_Amt2,Bar_Date, Bar_Month,Trannn)
df6_subset <- reactive({

# # Filter Data By Type "Billed" that need to still be paid
df6$Date <- as.Date(df6$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")
filter1_data <- subset(df6, Tran_Type == "Bill")

# Function to filter between 2 Dates
d <- format(as.Date(input$DI))
d1 <- format(as.Date(as.character(input$DI)) - 60)
d2 <- format(as.Date(as.character(input$DI)) - 30)

filter2_data <- filter1_data[filter1_data$Date >= d1 & filter1_data$Date <= d2,]
filter3_data <- na.omit(filter2_data)

filter4_data <- filter3_data[filter3_data$Billing_Num %in% hold,]

filter5_data <- subset(filter4_data,select = -c(Tran_Type,Bar_Date,Date,Bar_Month,Trannn)) 

return(filter5_data)

})

output$datetest <- renderTable(df6_subset(), spacing=c("xs"), align = NULL)
```

Comment: are you just trying to format the values so they have currency symbols attached?
if so `scales::dollar_format()` may be what you are looking for. [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/scales/versions/0.4.1/topics/dollar_format)

Comment: Yes, that is what I think I am trying to use; however, I am having trouble simply applying the format to the one column of the data table. Would you happen to know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume you are making your custom money format function with `dollar_format()`

```
Foodollar <- scales::dollar_format(negative_parens = TRUE, prefix = "*@*")
set.seed(49) #just for reproducability

df <- data.frame(Let = LETTERS[1:10], Money=rnorm(10, 1000, 150))
df
#   Let     Money
#1    A  948.5101
#2    B  907.9918
#3    C  746.9616
#4    D  908.0822
#5    E 1011.4537
#6    F  902.0824
#7    G  828.3860
#8    H 1328.9407
#9    I 1059.6365
#10   J  990.0883

df$Money <- Foodollar(df$Money)
df
#   Let       Money
#1    A   *@*948.51
#2    B   *@*907.99
#3    C   *@*746.96
#4    D   *@*908.08
#5    E *@*1,011.45
#6    F   *@*902.08
#7    G   *@*828.39
#8    H *@*1,328.94
#9    I *@*1,059.64
#10   J   *@*990.09
```

This turns the `df$Money` vector from a double into a character vector with the format specified by `Foodollar`

In other words, we make our function with `dollar_format` and then use that function to redefine the column we want.